# How to save user input and store for later use in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

So I've been trying to make a python program which can save all my ideas for future projects(I was bored).
Everything has been going well, its just that I ran into a small problem. To save my ideas, I use input() and then appending the input into a list. I realized that whenever you put something inside the list, whenever you re-run the program, the string you put into the list doesn't save. So I tried pickling but the data inside of it keeps getting overwritten. Could someone help me with this? I don't know where to start. Thanks for the help!

(Please keep in mind that I'm a beginner)

Comment: You can save the list/variable into a file so you can open it later

Comment: It would help if you can post the code that you already used to try to solve this, and then people will be hopefully able to see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a fun project for you, you can learn how to connect to a database and insert it as a row there. It is a simple procedure. You can try with SQLite, its easy and will be great learning for you.

Comment: Thanks! Ill try that! But where would I learn to do that?

Comment: Check out this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/pd-0G0MigUA) from Corey Schafer. He is a very good Python teacher. You can complete that tutorial and modify it to get the input from the user and call the necessary functions from the tutorial to create a DB row.

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, you want to save your data when it is closed and after opening again, you want to access it.
you can use databases and for small projects, it is enough to use [`sqlite`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html):

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE COMPANY
         (ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
         NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
         AGE            INT     NOT NULL,
         ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
         SALARY         REAL);''')

conn.close()
```

you can begin [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm) and see some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Even file handling will be helpful, try this: (The term "yield" refers here in python as generator - you can learn: https://www.w3schools.com/python/)

```
def store_ideas():
    print('Please place your ideas below, press enter to exit')
    while True:
        idea = input()
        if "quit" in idea or "exit" in idea:
            break
        else:
            yield idea

ideas = [x for x in store_ideas()]

with open('myideas.txt', 'a') as fp:
    for idea in ideas:
        fp.write(str(f'{idea}\n'))
```